# Why do I receive a type mismatch error message?

Tags: stata, type-mismatch

I have been trying to practice in Stata on the City of Toronto Humber Bay Parks Survey Results dataset  (https://open.toronto.ca/dataset/humber-bay-parks-survey-results-data/). Some of the values are blank for the survey questions and I was trying to clean them but I keep receiving an error message. I have given my commands below.

```
. replace Q1 = . if !missing(Q1)
type mismatch
r(109);
```

Comment: There are two general types of variables: string and numeric. This error message occurs when you are performing some operation that mixes these types up. Perhaps variable Q1 is a string variable, so you would need to type `replace Q1 = ""`

Comment: Replacing non-missing values with missing is legal but cleans your variable only by making **all** the values missing! So, it's not only a syntax error here; you need to be clear on what you really want. In fact, blank (empty) strings are just what they are and don't typically need further editing.

Comment: It takes a while to get used to the minimal style here, namely just ask a technical question and hope for a technical answer. So, we don't need explanations or apologies for being new to anything and we take thanks for granted.